# vue3 file upload get value undefined

Tags: vuejs3

I am trying to upload a file with vue, but the issue I am stuck with is this,
I can't access `this.imageFile.value` after selecting the photo.
The data I returned from setup but `undefined`.

Under normal conditions, `imageFile.value` works in setup.

```
<template>
  <img v-show="imageUrl" :src="imageUrl" alt="">
  <input @change="handleImageSelected,getdata" ref="fileInput" type="file" accept="image/*">
</template>
<script>
import {UseImageUpload} from "./use/UseImageUpload";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      Hello: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getdata() {
      this.Hello = this.imageFile.value
    }
  },
  setup() {
    let {imageFile, imageUrl, handleImageSelected} = UseImageUpload();

    return {
      imageFile,
      handleImageSelected,
      imageUrl,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

UseImageUpload.js

```
import {ref, watch} from "vue";

export function UseImageUpload() {
//image
    let imageFile = ref("");
    let imageUrl = ref("");

    function handleImageSelected(event) {
        if (event.target.files.length === 0) {
            imageFile.value = "";
            imageUrl.value = "";
            return;
        }

        imageFile.value = event.target.files[0];
    }

    watch(imageFile, (imageFile) => {
        if (!(imageFile instanceof File)) {
            return;
        }

        let fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.readAsDataURL(imageFile);

        fileReader.addEventListener("load", () => {
            imageUrl.value = fileReader.result;
        });
    });

    return {
        imageFile,
        imageUrl,
        handleImageSelected,
    };
}
```

Comment: why are you mixing up Options and Composition API and what exactly is this.Hello?

Comment: like this, when `input file` is uploaded.
`Use Image Upload` data is being entered and I will create data for the user with the incoming data.

Comment: try my answer if it does not work just leave a comment and I will take a further look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please try not to mix Options and Composition API - I know it might work but it is not necessary and in the most cases just an anti-pattern.
Composition API is there to replace the Options API or rather to give an alternative. They are just not supposed to work together or to be used together.

So this would improve your code:

```
setup() {
    const Hello = ref(null);
    const {imageFile, imageUrl, handleImageSelected} = UseImageUpload();

    function getdata() {
      Hello = imageFile.value
    }

    return {
      imageFile,
      handleImageSelected,
      imageUrl,
      getdata,
}
```

This should also fix your issue.

Comment: What problems can there be when mixed?

Comment: There might be no problems at all but the code looks better, is easier to read and the chance of getting an error increases because you might mix the two up. For example `.value` is only needed in `setup` and therefore you might use `.value` in Options API and this is just an error you could prevent with only using Composition API (or only using Options API)

Comment: You may be right, but I have a situation like this.
in the options api
in data

`
categories: {
        title: '',
        slug: '',
        seo: {
          title: '',
          dec: ''
        },
        language: 'en',
      },
`
There is a yield like this, how can I access it in the `composition api`.

Comment: the same as in my answer. You would just write: const categories = ref({ title: '', slug: '', seo: { title: '', dec: '' }, language: 'en', }). And to access it in `setup` you would just need to write categories.value and to use it in the template you just have to `return` it at the end of `setup` and access it in the template just as `categories`. Fort further information just look at the documentation https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html and set the left switch to "Composition"